# String to Response (http) in Java

Tags: java, http, response

I have a webservice call that receives a "Response" object but i am only able to receive it as a string, like the next one:

```
<200 OK,{"id":0,"amount":10000,"type":"Normal","userId":0,"userIdTeller":0,"createdAt":"15/12/2016 12:08","branchOfficeyId":0},{Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], Access-Control-Allow-Methods=[*], Access-Control-Allow-Headers=[*], Access-Control-Max-Age=[86400], Content-Type=[application/json], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Sun, 16 Oct 2016 13:21:02 GMT]}>
```

So, i am interested in the first part `<200 OK` and the second part `{"id":0,"amount":10000,"type":"Normal","userId":0,"userIdTeller":0,"createdAt":"15/12/2016 12:08","branchOfficeyId":0}` . I could easely split with `,` and take the first two elements, but if you know a class to unmarshall this string it would be better.

Best Regards!

Comment: What http client library are you using?

Comment: What do you use for the webservice? Is that JAX-RS implementation like Jersey? Could you please share the code which receives this?

Comment: It is a REST WebService, but i am only interested in parse this string.

Comment: THats a wierd string to get as response.  Are you sure that string is not the status code, response content, and attributes logged to the screen using some object's toString() method?  If so, please note that the toString() is made for logging and not for processing (for the most part).

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: It is not my code actually, i am just consuming the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom user defined bean class that would hold the details of your response entity object like id, amount etc along with its getters and setters

I would suggest using RestTemplate in the below fashion where your client code is being used.

Suppose that the JSON equivalent Java object are instances of **MyResponse** you can make use of the below client code.

```
private void getMyResponse()
{
    final String uri = "theRestWebServiceURI";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    MyResponse myResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, MyResponse.class);

}
```

Note that you may have to add Jackson Dependencies as Spring RestTemplate would be making use of its API for marshalling/un-marshalling JSON into Java objects and vice versa.

Comment: Yes i al ready have the class to unmarshall the json element but i was looking a previous class to unmarshall the response without writing custom code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate _unmarshall the response without writing custom code_

You *would* require to write a custom Java bean class for e.g. MyResponse as in the above comment. 
 
If you are talking about retrieving the response status and body both then you can check the Spring's  [RestTemplate's exchange](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-)  method.